# Maven puts JAR-file into package, that is not diplayed when running mvn dependency:list/tree -Dverbose=true

Tags: maven, jar, dependencies, war, pom.xml

We have an issue where hibernate-validator-3.0.0.ga.jar gets put into a warfile and due to a known incompatibility with a different hibernate-core version causes exceptions.

The problem is, that running

```
mvn dependency:list -Dverbose=true
```

or

```
mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose=true
```

Does not show any sign of hibernate-validator being a dependency of anything in the build.

Are there any good explanations / fixes for this kind of behaviour?

Maven Version is 2.2.1

Comment: Any trace in the output of `mvn -X clean install`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was a 2nd level dependency that was assigned to a nonexisting maven-scope. Somehow the evil hibernate-validators dependency was not shown in the dependency tree but ended up in the resulting JAR nontheless. Since we did not really need it we removed it from the POM and everything works as expected.

Comment: Could you post the `pom.xml` snippet, please?